# C# converting a stack to an array and sorting it

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, stack, return-type

I recently got into C# and I was trying to learn a bit about Stacks. I wanted to try and sort a stack, by first converting it to an array but I got a weird error.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static Stack<int> numbers = new Stack<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        int n = int.Parse(input[0]);
        int s = int.Parse(input[1]);
        int x = int.Parse(input[2]);

        input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            numbers.Push(int.Parse(input[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            numbers.Pop();
        }

        if (numbers.Count == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(0);
        else if (numbers.Contains(x))
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(Array.Sort(numbers.ToArray()));


    }
}
```

My issue is on the last else part of my code (last line) :

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

I was wondering why this is happening, when `Array.Sort()`, requires an Array as a parameter, and I pass `number.ToArray()`, which should return a new Array out of the *numbers* Stack.

Comment: You shouldn't sort a stack. It undermines the whole stack purpose.

Comment: `void` methods return nothing, so you can't use it in a method as argument. The next issue: you cannot `Console.WriteLine` a whole array. You need to enumerate it or use `String.Join(",", numbers)`.

Comment: `Array.Sort` does not return anything. It sorts an array in-place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error appears due the fact **Array.Sort** returns **void** and not the expected **array**.

**Additionally**, Console.WriteLine gets inputs and prints it to Console, it **can not** get array and print that array, it will only print you the actual array address.

In order to print array(or any collection) you should use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) which takes a collection and returns a string separated by delimiter.

Pretty straightforward using [System.Linq.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
numbers.OrderBy(num => num).ToArray();
```

**Example:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var numbers = new Stack<int>();
    numbers.Push(4);
    numbers.Push(1);
    numbers.Push(2);

    var numbersSorted = numbers.OrderBy(num => num).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbersSorted));
}
```

**Output:** 1, 2, 4

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zme4ZH)

Comment: This has the added advantage that the stack is left untouched.

Answer (score 2):

Array.Sort carries out an in-place sort on the array. It does not return a new sorted array. It is therefore a Void function.

Modify your code;

```
int[] numberArray = numbers.ToArray();
numberArray.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(numberArray);
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(numberArray)` isn't useful

Comment: Agreed - but not what the OP was querying.

Comment: No, but the next issue he will have. `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numberArray));` fixes it

Answer (score 2):

`Array.Sort` is a *void* method, you've to separate `Sort` and writing (to console) in two different statements.

I would suggest using `OrderBy` linq extension and `string.Join` together to have one liner display.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers.OrderBy(x=>x));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. In this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(Array.Sort(numbers.ToArray()));
```

The `Array.Sort` doesn't return anything (void) but you're passing to `Console.WriteLine` which expects a parameter.

You should replace the last else with this:

```
var numbersArray = numbers.ToArray();
Array.Sort(numbersArray);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an array variable before sorting, which you can then writeline.

```
    else
    {
        var array = numbers.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(array);
        Console.WriteLine(array);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert as `Array` Object. then sort your array and then you should use

`Console.WriteLine(array)` to print your Array.

```
int[] numberArray = numbers.ToArray(); //change to Array.
  numberArray.sort();                   // it will sort your Array.
  Console.WriteLine(numberArray);   //display the sorted Array.
```

instead of

```
 Console.WriteLine(Array.Sort(numbers.ToArray())); // here whatever Sort() method return will be printed as Output but infact Sort() returns void.
```

So Compile time your get `Error: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the responses. I am coming from Java, where you could directly print a collection, that's why I tried to do it like that.